# Can we create a google assistant Actions from API instead of google "gactions" CLI?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

To create a converstaion with google assistant we need to create a action from "gactions" (https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli) but it is a manual process.

Can same thing be done using api? Does google provides any rest api or any nodejs module to do the same?

Comment: There is no standard rest API that can be used.

Comment: For what it is worth, it looks like the gactions cli is written in go with debug symbols left in (maybe). It might be possible to reverse engineer if you really want.